# Nested CV and parallel computing in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am writing code to perform nested CV in Python, by using scikit-learn library.
My code core is the following:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()), ('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('myest', xgb.XGBRegressor())]) # Create my own pipeline to train and test

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv, refit=True, scoring = my_corrcoef_scorer) #scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error' # GridSearchCV for the inner loops

nested_score = cross_validate(clf, X=X, y=y, cv=outer_cv, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True, scoring = my_corrcoef_scorer) #scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error' # cross_validate for the outer loops
```

I would like to run my code on a Linux (Centos 7) machine, equipped with 32 CPUs, using more than one core. Unfortunately, I read the following sentence from [scikit-learn official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html):
**Warning You cannot nest objects with parallel computing (n_jobs different than 1).**

What does exactly mean? If I write `n_jobs = -1` (or > 1), the results will be wrong?
I ran my code multiple times, changing the n_jobs values in GridSearchCV (inner loop) and/or cross_validate (outer loop), but the results were equal..What am I missing?

Thanks for any answer!